# Woocommerce If cart item belongs to this category remove it

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ive got a page where the user fills out a form and it creates a custom woocommerce product

The user can only have this one type of product so I have made it so the product is put into the category "quotes"

However to ensure they have not already got it in the cart I have a script that empties the cart before adding the product

```
//check if product already in cart

WC()->cart->empty_cart(true);
WC()->session->set('cart', array());
if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {

// if no products in cart, add it
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );

}
    wp_redirect( home_url('/checkout/') ); exit;
```

But as there is an "addon" category too, I dont want any of those products being removed from the cart, only the products assigned to "quote" category

I have seen lots of ways to remove specific product from the cart, but I not anything where you can remove products belonging to a category.

I came up with the below using [Exclude certain categories when automatically adding products to the cart WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811983/exclude-certain-categories-when-automatically-adding-products-to-the-cart-woocom/60812150#60812150)

```
foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $prod_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

$category = quotes;

if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $prod_id ) ) {

 WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($prod_id);

}
}

    wp_redirect( home_url('/checkout/') ); exit;
```

and

```
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $prod_id =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
$category = quotes;

if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $prod_id ) ) {

 WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($prod_id);

}
}
```

But this does not work either.

Can anyone assist please

EDIT:

The product is created via a HTML/JQUERY form

Here is the PHP at the bottom of the form

```
// Add the shortcode to WordPress. 
add_shortcode('vehicle-quote', 'vehicle_quote');

function vehicle_quote_add_post(){
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'post' ){
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
            return;
        global $current_user;

        $user_id        = $current_user->ID;
        $post_title     = $_POST['post-title'];
        $post_content   = $_POST['posttext'];
        $tags           = $_POST['tags'];

        $length = filter_var($_POST['outlengthquestion'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $timefor = filter_var($_POST['outtimefor'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $essential = filter_var($_POST['outessential'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $contents = filter_var($_POST['outcontents'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $sterio = filter_var($_POST['outsterio'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    global $error_array;
        $error_array = array();

        if (empty($post_title)) $error_array[]='Please add a title.';


        if (count($error_array) == 0){

            $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
                'post_author'   => $user_id,
                'post_title'    => $post_title,
                'post_type'     => 'product',
                'meta_input' => array(
                'timefor_period' => $timefor,
                'length_level' => $length,          
                'essential' => $essential,
                'contents' => $contents,
                'sterioprotect' => $sterio,

            ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
        ) 
        );          



// select ID
$numberAsString = number_format($price, 2);
$product_id = $post_id;
      wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Quotes', 'product_cat' );
      update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', $numberAsString );
      add_post_meta($post_id, '_price', $numberAsString );
      add_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
      add_post_meta($post_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
      add_post_meta ($post_id, '_stock', 1);





add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'remove_from_cart', 10, 1 );
//check if product already in cart


WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );

/*}  */
    wp_redirect( home_url('/checkout/') ); exit;  


        } else {

        }
    }
}

add_action('init','vehicle_quote_add_post');
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
function remove_from_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    /********** SETTINGS **********/
    $remove_categories = array( 'quotes' ); // Remove these categories

    /********** LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS **********/

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Check if product belongs to a certain category
        if( has_term( $remove_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'remove_from_cart', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I go about this only happening if they get a new quote? I need the cart to empty other "quote" items when the user gets a new quote. Does that make sense?

Comment: To be clear. So, if a product of the category 'quotes' is added to the shopping cart, you want all other products of the same category to be removed from the shopping cart. Is it intended that the visitor/user will see a notification of this? (that the other products have been removed)

Comment: Not quite. So they go to the page "get a quote" and fill out a form which creates a quote product in woocommerce. Then they are redirected to the cart. However. IF when they do this, there is already a product in the cart which belongs to the category quotes, this should be removed and replaced by the one they just made. So they can only have 1 quote product in the cart at all times.

Comment: Well, to give an appropriate answer to that, it would be useful to know how that product is created via that form (code). That way we can test your question and provide the corresponding code.

Comment: Will add that to my question

Comment: Have added to my original question

Answer (score 1):

To remove cart item you should use `$cart_item_key` instead of `$prod_id`

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

     WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );

}
```